# Use ResultSet of SELECT...FOR UPDATE in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm using MySql 5.7 trying to create a stored procedure that will update a set of rows in a transaction and return the rows that were updated. After creating the locks, I then update those rows, but can't figure out how to use the ids returned from the `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` statement. Instead I have to scan the table again in the update statement looking for the rows I just locked. Here's an example of my procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cleanUp()
BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;

        SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.state = 'foobar' AND t.value < 10 FOR UPDATE;

        UPDATE t SET t.state = 'fizzbuzz' WHERE t.state = 'foobar' AND t.value < 10;

        COMMIT;
END //
```

I'd prefer to not have to scan the table twice for `t.state = 'foobar' AND t.value < 10`. I'd also like to guarantee that I *only* update the rows I just locked, not other rows that might have been changed to meet that criteria mid-transaction.

Is there a way to use the results of `SELECT..FOR UPDATE` in the `UPDATE` statement so I can update rows by id instead?

Note: I've tried loading the results into a temp table and using a cursor and both do not work.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL can't declared variable as table, so you need o write the select in a FROM clause, which can for example do as IN clause like the query below

> ```
> CREATE TABLe t(id int, state varchar(10), value int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t VALUEs(1,'foobar',1),(2,'foobar',1),(3,'foobar',1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE cleanUp()
> BEGIN
>         
>        START TRANSACTION;
>         UPDATE t SET t.state = 'fizzbuzz' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM t WHERE t.state = 'foobar' AND t.value < 10 FOR UPDATE) t1 );
>         COMMIT;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL cleanUp()
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t
> ```
>
> ```
> id | state    | value
> -: | :------- | ----:
>  1 | fizzbuzz |     1
>  2 | fizzbuzz |     1
>  3 | fizzbuzz |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=483ccba3f43cdd47c01691545c514d6b)*

Comment: this answer not explain how use "for update" construction

Comment: it show clearly that the select is wandered into the FROM clause, as mysql doesn't support table as variable